# ElasticSearch problems about garbled

Tags: elasticsearch

There are some garbled in the elasticsearch, like this:
I am a good body ?????(***this part should be*** )
Are there some settings about encoding in the elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes there is an subject in the documentation you can check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/languages.html But I think, your question is not enough to be able to answer. Can you give some extra information?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch does support every Unicode code point without exception, so the encoding issue you are having is most likely happening during the indexing request or search you are performing.

Also note that indexing "" without telling Lucene how to do it will not result in any searchable token, as this sign is considered punctuation by the standard tokenizer [See reference here on how to index and search emoji](https://jolicode.com/blog/search-for-emoji-with-elasticsearch).